# What is the difference between Yago and DBpedia taxonomies?

Tags: ontology, dbpedia

Both of them are widely used to type DBpedia resources but it seems that YAGO has much more classes or concepts organized using rdfs:subClassOf predicate. Despite this, it is not clear if, for example, that class hierarchy is a DAG (like in DBpedia), how many classes conform it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

DBpedia is a community effort to extract structured information from Wikipedia. In this sense, both YAGO and DBpedia share the same goal of generating a structured ontology. The projects differ in their foci. In YAGO, the focus is on precision, the taxonomic structure, and the spatial and temporal dimension. For a detailed comparison of the projects, see Chapter 10.3 of our AI journal paper "YAGO2: A Spatially and Temporally Enhanced Knowledge Base from Wikipedia".

[Link: http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/publications/aij.pdf]